# How to use original image url in paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

What is the original path of image that uploaded by paperclip.

```
has_attached_file :attachment,
  :url  =>           ":rails_root/public/photos/images/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
  :default =>        ":rails_root/public/images/no-image-available.png",
  :styles =>          style_options,
  :default_style =>   :gallery
```

and style_options are

```
  style_options = {  :thumbnail => {:geometry => '100x100'},
                     :profile_gallery =>  {:geometry => '184x247'}
                  }
```

In my public folder create 3 folder while one image upload 1. thumbnail, 2. profile_gallary 3. original.

In my view file I call

```
<%= photo.thumbnail_url %>
```

My Question is I want to use original path that upload image. I don't want to use thumnail for any particular url. How can I use original path.

Thanks for Advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<%= photo.attachment.url(:original) %>
```

That will give you the path to the original file, you can also get the other styles if needed:

```
<%= photo.attachment.url(:thumbnail) %>
<%= photo.attachment.url(:profile_gallery) %>
```